# How to pass an integer from label to button_Click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How to pass an integer from label to button_Click

```
private void button2_Click(int rc, object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void label10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

int rack=11

button2_Click(rack);

}
```

How to transfer?

Comment: as a usability thing, click values on labels are not very clear to the user unless the text of the label says click here.. In answer to your question PLB's solution should work

Answer (score 1):

I do not really know what you are trying to do but you may call `button2_Click(int rc, object sender, EventArgs e)` under `label10_Click` where `rc` is `rack`, `sender` is `sender` and `e` is `e` if you want to use `rc` under `button2_Click` as `rack` since `rack` is not accessible under `button2_Click`

**Example**

```
private void button2_Click(int rc, object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //DoSomething with rc
    //MessageBox.Show(rc.ToString());    
}

private void label10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rack = 11;
    button2_Click(rack, sender, e);
}
```

However, it's recommended to declare `rack` publicly if you would like to use `rack` without using a constructor to get the value of `rack`

**Example**

```
int rack = 0; //Initialize rack as an int of value 0
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    //MessageBox.Show(rack.ToString());    
}

private void label10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rack = 11; //Set rack to 11
    button2_Click(sender, e); //Call button2_Click
}
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can do:

```
button2_Click(rack, sender, e);
```

But it does not seem to be very logical for me. If you want to simulate `button2` click you can also pass `button2` instead of `sender` in second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to pass value , you can access label's text anywhere by using `label19.Text`